# Button in UITableView is appearing twice in iPad Master View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, ios6

Created a UITableView programmatically, data in my tableview in iPad Master View Controller is loaded dynamically, i am putting a button in the last cell, but the button is showing up again in the tableview underneath the cell... First time when the code is executed, the button appears only once, but next time it shows up twice... Here is the code...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if([_objects count] > 1)
{

    if(indexPath.row == [_objects count])
    {            

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        //set the position of the button
        button.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + 50, cell.frame.origin.y + 15, 225, 30);
        [button setTitle:@"Hide me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(customActionPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:100.0/255.0 blue:220.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
        cell.textLabel.text = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@", [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

for ex:: here is a snapshot of the tableview (how can i put the image here???)

1. aaa
2. bbb
3. ccc
4. ddd
5. eee
6. UIButton

   UIButton is appearing again here in the tableview

   Here is the image link http://s10.postimg.org/fwarb2661/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_shot_28_Dec_2013_10_57_32_A.png

   any help is appreciated, thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post some code here

Comment: thanks, added some code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please write bellow code :

```
 if (cell)

   {

     cell =nil;

   }
```

before creating your tableview cell

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

//write here

```
if (cell)

   {

     cell =nil;

   }
```

//*****

```
if (cell == nil) {

   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
```

Comment: Man, it is working perfect... but why was the cell repeating, can u pls tell me ??? Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: @grk please share your screenshot with me then i can check your problem.

Comment: Here is the image link http://s10.postimg.org/fwarb2661/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_shot_28_Dec_2013_10_57_32_A.png

Answer (score 0):

For set background image in cell plese use bellow code :-

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X, Y, 277, 58)];

imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

imageView.opaque = NO;

imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];

cell.backgroundView = imageView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your table view is using the same cell again.
Make sure you delete the button from the cell every time.

Would help to see your code so I can point to you exact location...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
(void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
}
```

In the method set the button to `nil` or any other elements showing twice. The cell is being reused and you need to run `prepareForReuse` to empty the old cells.